# Replace text with textbox contains this text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html document that contains some text, assume there is one word in each line in the document, I want to replace each word with a textbox that contains this word. Is there any easy way to do that (in javascript)? A practical example:suppose I have a html document that contains a table that contains my grade, and there is a cell contains the average, I want to replace every grade with a textbox and then let the user to edit the grades to calculate the new average

Comment: Could you expand you question, perhaps some example html?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable. Maybe you will like it.

Comment: Do you really want to replace all words in the HTML document ? Not just the ones of some specific containers (for example paragraphs) ?

Comment: what I gave is just an example, suppose I have a html document that contains a  table that contains my grade, and there is a cell contains the average, I want to replace every grade with a textbox and then let the user to edit the grades to calculate the new average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all these words are in a `div`, here's how I approached the problem with jQuery (sorry if you were looking for pure JS)

HTML

```
<div>These are all yours words. You want to split ALL of these to new textboxes</div>
```

jQuery

```
var currentText = $("div").text();
var arrWords = currentText.split(" ");

$("div").empty();
var newHtml = "";

for (var i = 0; i < arrWords.length; i++) {
    newHtml += "<input type='text' value='" + arrWords[i] + "'/><br/>";
}

$("div").append(newHtml);
```

Heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SeYqU/2/

Comment: You mean each word is already in its own element ? You're really over-simplifying the problem, I think.

Comment: Yeah I know..I just cant imagine a way to split EVERY word on a page...short of splicing on spaces, and doing it that way :\

Comment: Updated the answer and fiddle.

Comment: what I gave is just an example, suppose I have a html document that contains a table that contains my grade, and there is a cell contains the average, I want to replace every grade with a textbox and then let the user to edit the grades to calculate the new average

Comment: Well that is a completely different problem, a much easier one at that. Update your question with your HTML table structure and I'm sure you'll get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/3VY4D/), but you need to explain yourself better

```
<div>this</div>
<div>word</div>
<div>or</div>
<div>that</div>
<div>word</div>

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
    var word = div.textContent,
        textArea = document.createElement("input");

    div.textContent = "";
    textArea.value = word;
    div.appendChild(textArea);
});
```